# How can i host a public website from my computer?

Tags: web, hosting

I've tried hundreds of websites and tutorials, all of which only tell me how to host a local website, but can I host a website that people from other networks can join, and can I add my recently bought domain to it as well?

Comment: There are a few broad steps with some details in each step, beyond the scope of this site (and the question is probably off topic). But to get you started: (1) you need to pick a domain name and purchase it at a provider, such as godaddy.com or a number of other options, (2) you need to set up a computer at home as an HTTP server and make an IP address (which is probably dynamic) available on the internet that can access it (via TMZ configured in your WAN/wifi router), (3) through your provider configure DNS for your (dynamic) IP and your domain name.

Comment: You should, though, do an internet search on "how to host your own website from home". Honestly, it's easier to use any one of many inexpensive web hosting services.